# Javascript: How to update IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I'm trying to create a chrome extension, but I am having some trouble updating my DB.

In the code below I am using `index.get` to the the object that contains a certain value. If such an object doesn't exist I will create a new one, which works just fine.

But if the DB contains an object with the specified value, I want to append a new object to an array (`allMessages`) that is inside the object I searched for. The details doesn't really matter in this case.

What is important is to find out if the way I'm adding this new obj to the array (`allMessages`) is a valid way of updating the database.

```
records.forEach((person) => {
  console.log("here1");
  const index = objectStore.index("urlKeyValue");
  let search = index.get(person.urlKeyValue);

  search.onsuccess = function (event) {
    if (search.result === undefined) {
      // no record with that key
      let request = objectStore.add(person);

      request.onsuccess = function () {
        console.log("Added: ", person);
      };
    } else {

// here I'm iterating an array that is inside the obj I searched for, 
// and then checking if the key for that array matches **theUserId**
      for (userObj of event.target.result.allMessages) {
        if (theUserId == Object.keys(userObj)) {

// is this part correct. Is it possible to update the DB this way?
          let objToAdd1 = {
            time: person.allMessages[0][theUserId][0].time,
            msg: person.allMessages[0][theUserId][0].msg,
          };

          let currentObj = userObj[theUserId];
          let updatedObj = currentObj.push(objToAdd1);
        }
      }
)}
```

Comment: You have to use [update](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/update)

Comment: Can I use update even though Im adding an object to an already existing array? And not chaning the value of an already existing variable?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how I would go about using `update` in my case?

Comment: Looks like the array is a part of one record, which means you can only overwrite the entire record with the new value e.g. by using `put`. It doesn't matter conceptually if it's inside a cursor or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using **objectStore.openCursor** you can update only part of the record.
The following updates only book prices.

```
  const transaction = db.transaction("books", "readwrite");
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore("books");
  records = [{ id: "kimetu", price: 600 }];

  records.forEach((book) => {
    const index = objectStore.index("id");
    const search = index.get(book.id);
    search.onsuccess = () => {
      if (search.result === undefined) {
        const request = objectStore.add(book);
        request.onsuccess = () => {
          console.log("Added: ", book);
        };
      } else {
        const request = objectStore.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(book.id));
        request.onsuccess = () => {
          const cursor = request.result;
          if (cursor) {
            cursor.value.price = 1000;
            const updateRequest = cursor.update(cursor.value);
            updateRequest.onsuccess = () => {
              console.log("Updated: ", cursor.value.price);
            };
            cursor.continue();
          }
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `IDBKeyRange.only(book.id)` searches for the value `book.id` but what i want is to search for the *key*. How can I do that?

Comment: In your case I think it's IDBKeyRange.only(person.urlKeyValue).